# Importing existing gradle project into intelli J idea

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

Intelli J 2019.1 Community. 
Eclipse 2018.09
Gradle 5.1

When I import my existing Gradle project into eclipse all dependencies work fine. But when I try to import the same project into IntelliJ. I am getting "Cannot resolve method ..." error. Any idea what I might be missing?

I tried in IntelliJ syncronize, invalidate the cache and restart, etc. None of them worked out.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you have compilation errors in intellij only? Can you give more info about the error? In Eclipse, are you importing with the eclipse plugin, or with buildship?

Comment: is intellij using the same jdk as eclipse?

Comment: Please check that dependencies are shown in Gradle tool window and in "Project Structure | Modules | Dependencies"

Comment: Yes both of them use the jdk 8. As error: it says " cannot resolve methodXXX"